# How is the following theorem the princple of *complete* induction?

Tags: induction, cardinals, ordinals

The following is from page $19$ of Holz' *Introduction to Cardinal Arithmetic*.

[image]

As I understand it (see [here](https://ma225.wordpress.ncsu.edu/complete-induction/)), ordinary and complete induction (on $\omega$) work as follows:

- **Ordinary Induction:** if $P(0)$ holds and if $P(k)\implies P(k+1)$ for any $k$, then $P(n)$ holds for any $n$.
- **Complete Induction:** if $P(0)$ holds and if $P(1)\land\cdots\land P(k)\implies P(k+1)$ for any $k$, then $P(n)$ holds for any $n$.

---

Shouldn't **Corollary 1.2.8** be called *ordinary* induction? As I see it, complete induction would instead take a form such as
$$A\subseteq \omega\land 0\in A\land\forall \alpha\in A (\beta <\alpha \implies \beta\in A)\implies A=\omega.$$

Comment: I'm used to different adjectives being used to distinguish the two, but yeah, that looks like weak / simple / ordinary induction to me.

Comment: Your statement of complete induction at the end (what would sometimes be called strong induction) doesn't look correct, though.  What you have written is that every subset of $\omega$ that is an initial segment must be all of $\omega$, which is certainly not true.

You want something like $$A\subseteq \omega\land\left(\forall \alpha\in \omega (\forall \beta <\alpha (\beta\in A) \implies \alpha \in A)\right)\implies A=\omega.$$